# GWT vertical layout

Tags: html, css, gwt, layout

I need a vertical layout, which would fill browser's viewport top to bottom, with on overflow (scrollbars). I need to layout widgets on the top, and on the bottom, and have one widget in the center which would stretch to fill the remaining space.

There seems to be DockLayoutPanel for this purpose, the problem with it is that it forces me to specify widget sizes, and I don't know the sizes of the top/bottom widgets before the browser does it's layouting job, which is tricky (buggy) to track. I cannot find the right moment when to measure my widgets, and I don't want to do this kind of layouting code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What about the body's onload event?

Comment: you cannot register body onload event from within GWT, and that's why I suppose it's not best practice. One more thing, one might need to load some additional content right after module loads, which in turns changes DOM, and then layouting needs to be redone. it's a hell, I started to use DockLayouyPanel

Answer (score 0):

onAttach is event fired by every widget when it is been added to its parent once any widget as been added then you can get the offset height and width.

extend panel class for top, central and bottom then when all these panels has been added to parent try to get width and height..